# Ограничение доступа при I-net соединении

Tags: sql-server

SQL server и клиент соединяются через `I-net`. Как ограничить доступ к серверу, т.е. доступ только к SQL server и не каким другим ресурсам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Закройте брандмауэром все порты кроме [**1433-го**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932)

Comment: Уже делал. Не помогает!

Comment: В смсле не помогает? Есть доступ к чему то еще? Посмотрите какие порты открыты.

Comment: Извините. Переинстоаллировал комп. и пока все нормально. Спасибо!